# 1 nest to control all vales on UFH manifold?

Tags: plumbing, wiring, thermostat, nest

We are having an extension done and intend on having all underfloor heating in the new area. Currently we have a valiant combi boiler supplying the main house which has been T'd off with a valve for the underfloor heating when we are ready to install its manifold. I wanted to install a Nest thermostat for the main house and a second Nest to control the underfloor heating. Given the size of the room (50 square metres) I've been told it splitting it into 3 zones would be best. I'm not quite sure how that will work with the Nest, as their support desk mentioned that 1 nest can only control 1 zone. Is what I want achievable ? And if so, how would it be hooked up? I.e what do I need to do at this stage.

Thanks

Comment: Would you want all three zones to come on at the same time?

Comment: That's is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nest can only control one zone at a time, but that's ok, because it sounds like there's only one "control zone" in your system.

Your heating system may work better if its split into three sections, but since the will all come on at the same time, the Nest should be able to control all three at the same time.  What the Nest can do is control each zone separately.

Typical control systems have a "hot" wire and a "common" wire.  Just tie all the commons together and all the hots together and then run a single common and hot to the Nest for control.